# android ConstraintLayout Flow : align items from right to left

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, right-to-left, constraintlayout-helper-widget-flow

I'm using android `ConstraintLayout` Flow , and I have to arrange items from right to left , something like this :

[image]

`XML` code :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
            android:id="@+id/flow"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:flow_horizontalStyle="spread_inside"
            app:flow_maxElementsWrap="4"
            app:flow_verticalGap="29dp"
            app:flow_wrapMode="aligned"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="item1 , item2 , ..."
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/headerTextView" />
```

**Note** : our `supportsRtl` set False in the Manifest ...

**how can I do this ?!**

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'm looking for RTL support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found and it worked was to set rotationY=180f on parent (our ConstraintLayout) and then set rotationY=180f on each item we have in the ConstraintLayout too.

Answer (score 5):

There is a workaround to add items to the flow from right to left by rotating the `ConstraintLayout` on Y-direction with `android:rotationY="180"`

This will reverse the entire layout including each individual element in the flow; so, in the below demo you'd see the text reversed as well like:

[image]

To fix this, we have to do the reverse back for each individual element. This requires a ViewGroup, so here each individual element is wrapped in a `FrameLayout` for that purpose.

Demo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rotationY="180">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:id="@+id/flow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9"
        app:flow_horizontalGap="8dp"
        app:flow_maxElementsWrap="3"
        app:flow_verticalBias="1"
        app:flow_verticalGap="8dp"
        app:flow_verticalStyle="packed"
        app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotationY="180"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotationY="180"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotationY="180"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotationY="180"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotationY="180"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotationY="180"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:text="6"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotationY="180"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:text="7"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotationY="180"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:text="8"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotationY="180"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:text="9"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I am using flow layout and got it to work with:

app:flRtl="true">